# R: iconv to remove non-ASCII characters not working

Tags: r, iconv

I have a dataset containing Twitter data and I'm trying to remove all non-ASCII characters from it. 
The dataset's rows currently look like this:

'Looking forward to tonight and rooting for who has strong competition. Sh\u2026'

and I would like to get this:

'Looking forward to tonight and rooting for who has strong competition. Sh'

As the encoding of my csv file was 'unknown', I've forced it to 'UTF-8' using `read.csv2(file, encoding='UTF-8')`. Also, I've converted my text column into a vector using `as.vector(x)` and then tried:

```
iconv(x, from = "UTF-8", to = "ASCII", sub = '')
```

and

```
sapply(x, function(row) iconv(row, "UTF-8", "ASCII", sub=""))
```

as solutions I found in other similar questions. However, nothing changed in the dataset or in the vector.

Any ideas of what the issue could be?

Comment: Have you not assigned the return value from `iconv` back to another object? If I do: `s = 'competition. Sh\u2026' ; s = iconv(s, from = "UTF-8", to = "ASCII", sub = '') ; print(s)` then `s` is updated. Conversion doesn't happen "in place", you have to assign the returne value.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try `read.csv(stringi::stri_read_lines("yourfile"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. You can also try `readr::read_csv("yourfile")` or `data.table::fread("yourfile")` as they, too, can deal with encoding "issues" a bit friendlier than base R `read.csv`

Comment: Thank you both! @hrbrmstr I've tried everything you suggested but nothing seems to work. I've noticed that `stri_enc_mark(x)` returns 'ASCII'. I've then used `all(stri_enc_isutf8(x))` and it returns 'TRUE'. However, when I check the encoding with `Encoding(x)`, it still returns 'unknown', and consequently the `iconv` function won't work.